# What does "edge" mean when talking about Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, terminology

In [this Azure SQL intro page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/#product-overview), they state:

> A consistent SQL experience from edge to cloud
>
> Get a unified experience across your entire SQL portfolio and a full range of deployment options from edge to cloud.

What does edge mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does edge mean here?

It's an offering targeting the [IoT/Embedded market](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/edge/).

> **Real-time data insights for IoT servers, gateways, and devices**
>
> Azure SQL Edge, a robust Internet of Things (IoT) database for edge computing, combines capabilities such as data streaming and time series with built-in machine learning and graph features. Extend the industry-leading Microsoft SQL engine to edge devices for consistent performance and security across your entire data estate, from cloud to edge. Develop your applications once and deploy them anywhere across the edge, your on-premises datacenter, or Azure.